# How do I get the Laurel Wreath?

Tags: all-my-gods

I am playing All My Gods and in order to progress, I need to acquire the Laurel Wreath so I can then use another obelisk of the gods to open up more space for my civilization to grow into.

Problem is, I have no idea how to get the Laurel Wreath. I am not sure if I need more civilization points, or need to research certain things, or have a certain number/type of buildings.

What do I need to do to get the Laurel Wreath?

Comment: Not played the game, but I got "The wreath will be given when you complete one of the requests." from [here](http://forums.bigfishgames.com/posts/list/201547.page) if that helps at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build a lumber mill to get the laurel wreath